# Style in php function

Tags: php

https://www.arhantayoga.org/reserve-parking/ I have a drop down on this page . 10 Jun - 5 Jul 2019 (12 Parking left) below function append a number of parking left in the setect options . I want 12 parking left to have different color.

```
add_filter( 'gplc_remove_choices', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'gplc_pre_render_choice', 'my_add_how_many_left_message', 10, 5 );
function my_add_how_many_left_message( $choice, $exceeded_limit, $field, 
$form, $count ) {
$limit = rgar( $choice, 'limit' );
$how_many_left = max( $limit - $count, 0 );
$message = "($how_many_left Parking left)";
$choice['text'] = $choice['text'] . "  $message";`
return $choice;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show us what you have tried and explain what is the particular issue you have. We are here to help but we are not a free online coding service.

Comment: These resources may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: The style should be added in the php lines that generates the HTML code. I can not make a suggestion based on the code you provided, so please update the question.